# what are the best practices for bolting a ring terminal to a steel panel?

Tags: grounding, terminal, mechanical-assembly, wire-terminals

i have made several new bolted grounding points in project boxes and in my car. i don't have data on how long they last, but i been following a strategy like this to connect a ring terminal:

- drill a hole in the steel
- grind or sand off any paint or detritus around the hole (ideally both sides, but sometimes only one side is accessible)
- deburr the metal with steel wool or a file
- line up the terminal with the hole and secure them loosely with a bolt and nut,or two nuts in areas of high concern
- spray those parts with De-Ox-It
- tighten the nut(s)

This mostly works, but should I use washers? How many and what kind? Is another conductive solution better suited than De-Ox-It? What should I know about the amount of torque applied? Does it matter if the bolt tarnishes over time?

Comment: Torque ? - Just make sure it is fasten good and tight. Your steps are right. It's enough for me from conducting terms. To finalize, just add weather proof. Could be silicon sealant or epoxy resin. That what i did on all my antenna projects.

Answer (score 2):

Using a serrated washer between the terminal and the chassis will improve electrical conductivity and reduce or eliminate the effect oxidation has on the electrical connection.

[image]