# Bolting a steel ring terminal to a steel tab on IGBT?

Tags: terminal, mechanical-assembly, wire-terminals

This is a similar question to one answered here: [what are the best practices for bolting a ring terminal to a steel panel?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/268865/what-are-the-best-practices-for-bolting-a-ring-terminal-to-a-steel-panel)

However, the main difference is that I am not attaching a ring terminal to a chassis. I am attaching it to the steel tab on an IGBT.

Should I still use a serrated washer? What is the best bolt material? Steel as well?

Should it be brazed to ensure the highest conductivity? (Serviceability is not much of an issue)

I just want to make sure this is done correctly. Thank you!

[image: Example connection of ring terminal to steel IGBT tab]

Datasheet for CM600DY-12NF IGBT http://www.pwrx.com/pwrx/docs/cm600dy_12nf.pdf

Comment: What does the datasheet for the mystery IGBT say?

Comment: What is the environment? Automotive?

Comment: Are you sure the tab on that IGBT is steel?  Maybe I'm not understanding what you are saying, but steel is not a material used in semiconductors for electrical connection.

Comment: I've attached the datasheet. I am unsure what the material is. I assumed it was steel, but the datasheet does not say what it is. This is an automotive application. My dad built an AC motor controller and I was trying to research the best way to connect HV connections. He says just bolting it is fine, but I wanted to be extra sure.

Comment: OK, definitely not steel then, likely tinned copper.  Bolting is fine, that's exactly what's intended for these modules.  You could use a lock washer under the bolt, but make sure the contact between the lug and the IGBT terminal is clean and flat.

Comment: Thank you @JohnD that is exactly what I needed to know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tabs are usually tin plated copper as these need to be solder to the substrate.

I would not use a star washer. These are great for earth bonding points to break the insulative oxide layers (lower contact resistance), they will not offer that great of a contact surface area and thus your current density will be higher and overall resistance higher.

I would personally advocate using copper washer with the designated tightening torque

Comment: Thank you for the clear and concise answer. This is just what I needed!